# Ruby on Rails Why do I get the error: undefined method `email' for 69:Fixnum when trying to send an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, in my RoR application I have a cinema system where users have preferences, which include saving their favourite actor. What I am trying to do is get it so that when a new film is added, if users have the any of film's actors saved as their favourite they will get an email notifying them of the film. At the minute I am trying to do a simplified version of this where only one user will be emailed if the film has the actor Liam Neeson and the email will be the same one that is received when the user sign's up to the website (I already have this functionality working).

films_controller:

```
def create
    @film = Film.new(film_params)
    if @film.save
        user = Perference.where(actor: "Liam Neeson").pluck(:user_id).first
        if not user.blank?
            UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver
        end
        redirect_to @film
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

user_mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'no-reply@thorcinemas.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

welcome_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Thor Cinemas, <%= @user.first_name %>!</h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to Thor Cinemas,
      your username is: <%= @user.first_name %> <%= @user.last_name %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And schema:

```
 create_table "films", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "title"
     t.string   "synopsis"
     t.string   "director"
     t.string   "cast1"
     t.string   "cast2"
     t.string   "cast3"
     t.date     "release_date"
     t.string   "warnings"
     t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
     t.string   "image_url"
     t.string   "certificate_id"
     t.integer  "category_id"
     t.integer  "hours"
     t.integer  "minutes"
     t.string   "video_url"
  end

create_table "perferences", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.text     "colour"
    t.text     "actor"
  end

 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "password_digest"
     t.string   "role"
     t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
     t.string   "first_name"
     t.string   "last_name"
     t.string   "house_no"
     t.string   "street"
     t.string   "town"
     t.string   "postcode"
     t.string   "email"
     t.date     "date_of_birth"
  end
```

But the get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in FilmsController#create
undefined method `email' for 69:Fixnum
```

I know that there are problems with my code at the minute, for example it isn't best practice to have cast1, cast2, and cast3 in the films table and there isn't any validation to ensure that users are only emailed if their favourite actor matches the films's actor, but I am just trying to send an email at the minute and will deal with these later.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an `Integer` (`user_id`) to the variable `user` from your controller to the mailer. You need to pass `user` object instead.

I can't see your models, however, assuming you have set proper associations, you need to update your code for finding user like this:

```
user = Perference.where(actor: "Liam Neeson").first.user
```

Comment: Ok, now I am trying to send a specific email, I have added the method: `def favourite_actor(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/films'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Your favourite actor stars in a new film')
  end` to user_mailer and `UserMailer.favourite_actor(user).deliver` to films_controller but get this error: `undefined method `favourite_actor' for UserMailer:Class` any advice?

Comment: I suggest you mark RAJ's answer as accepted and create another question, so that you acknowledge his efforts to help you and get your new question more visibility on the main questions' page =]

Comment: Thanks @Thyago. Benjs.1, you can paste link of the new question here, so that we can help you.